# Cpanel My php code minified and not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, cpanel

Hi my project is install Cpanel server but not working this Cpanel my php code minifide look at the http://prntscr.com/7vd5gt left picture is local php file right picture server Cpanel php file. Php file error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/cinselterapi/public_html/application/controllers/site.php on line 2

help me please.

Server php version http://prntscr.com/7vd7kb
Apllication frame work is Codeigniter 2.0

Comment: We don't go "outside" for code, and ESPECIALLY don't go outside for **PICTURES** of code.

Comment: Also, there is no apparent error in the code I can see. Please consider posting enough so that we can see if/where the error is.

Comment: my php code picture http://prntscr.com/7vd5gt

this over picture left page local php file then right page install Cpanel over php file

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Minifying php code is a horrible idea and just don't. The syntax error usually means there's a missing `}` or `end`-statement somewhere. If CPanel broke your php file while uploading you should probably try to upload it manually with i.e. FTP.

Comment: yes upload manually with file zilla but result match http://prntscr.com/7vd5gt

Comment: I second @JohanPalmfjord. I can't think of any good reason to minify PHP code. As you are finding it causes more problems than it solved. I assume you might be confusing it with HTML/JS minification which is beneficial because it has to pass over the network where size matters, but PHP code isn't sent to the client. Don't minify and you're problem is solved.

Answer (score -1):

my php code picture http://prntscr.com/7vd5gt

this over picture left page local php file then right page install Cpanel over php file